# Выполнение js скрипта переданного из php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Всем привет, создаю расширение для хрома. Возникла надобность выполнять разные разные скрипты на разных страницах.

```
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": [ "https://*/*", "http://*/*" ],
      "js": ["content_scripts/end.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
```

Сейчас выполняется вот этот скрипт. В нём я беру url страницы и ajax`ом отправляю к себе на сайт.

На сайте есть массив сайтов, допустим он выглядит вот так:

```
$url_array = array(
    'https://vk.com',
    'https://ok.ru'
);
```

Если сайт найден в массиве, то должен отправляться обратно определённый скрипт, если нет, то другой:

```
if ($search != NULL){
    echo '
    <script>
        console.log("Есть");
    </script>
    ';
}else{
    echo '
    <script>
        console.log("Нет");
    </script>
    ';
}
```

Потом просто вывожу это все в

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Все вроде бы просто, но как и ожидалось - просто все, что пришло с сайта выводится вот так в консоль:

```
end.js:14 

    <script>
        console.log("Есть");
    </script>
```

А нужно, что бы то, что пришло с сайта не просто выводилось, а ещё и выполнялось, как это можно реализовать? 
Думаю, что можно передавать через json, но будет ли разница?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) должна по идее помочь решить вашу задачу

```js
eval('console.log("Есть");')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало!

Comment: @Apelsin2020 лучше маленькое подтверждение решения вопроса, чем большое спасибо =)

Comment: Через 6 минут можно будет, обязательно поставлю